# How can I replace one element with list of elements using jsoup?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I just want to replace one element with different list of elements, I can't find a way how to do it. Where `dynamicContentHtmls` is list of Elements and `element` is the one which should be replaced.

My experimental code:

```
int i=0;
    for (Element element: dynamicContents){
        //element.remove();
        element.append(dynamicContentHtmls.get(i));
        //TextNode text = new TextNode(dynamicContentHtmls.get(i), "");
        //element.replaceWith(text);
        //element.html().replaceAll(element.html(),  
        //dynamicContentHtmls.get(i));
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved it by doing this:

```
element.parent().append(dynamicContentHtmls.get(i));
element.remove();
```